# How to split, add text for each split and gzip file

Tags: bash, gzip, split

I want to take a huge file `data.txt` and:

1. Split it by 256m
2. Add the first 3 lines of `data.txt` to each split file
3. gzip it

`data.txt` looks like:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
<data>
<data>
<data>
...
<few million rows>
<data>
```

The end result would be that each split file will have the same first 3 lines

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

The most efficient way I know how to do it is in the memory. If I leave step 2 it would look like:

```
split --bytes=256M -d -a 3 --filter='gzip > $FILE.gz' data.txt split/data_
```

But with step 2 I'm not sure how to do it without split the gzip into a separate command, thus writing the files to disk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make the filter more complex:

```
split -C 256M -d -a 3 --filter '(head -n 3 data.txt; cat) | gzip > $FILE.gz' <(tail -n +4 data.txt) data_
```

This skips the first three lines of `data.txt`, and then reintroduces them into every split section.

I’m using `-C` instead of `--bytes` to ensure that the split files contain full records.